# Using LinQ to check if a column contains comma-delimited values

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I have a column in a database that contains the id from a different table. However it can have several id's and stores them as comma delimited values. I want to use linq to find which results from the first query contain a certain id from the second table.

```
int selectedDestIndex = (int)objQry3.FirstOrDefault();
            var objQry = from objD in db.TourBookingTransactions
                      join tbt in db.TourBookingTours
                      on objD.TourBookingHeaderID equals tbt.TourBookingHeaderID
                      join tmst in db.ToursMsts
                      on tbt.TourID equals tmst.TourId
                         where objD.DTTM >= selectedStartDate
                         && objD.DTTM < selectedEndDate
                         select new { email = objD.Email, destinationIds = tmst.DestinationIds };
            var qry = objQry.ToList().Where(w => (w.destinationIds).Split(',').Contains(selectedDestIndex.ToString()));
```

At the moment I am getting a list of email addresses and the column with the list of ids from one query. I also then have a query that gives me the ID I am searching for. I only want the email addresses that contain this id. When I run the code as it is, I get an error saying you cannot do .contains with a string []. I have tried searching on google but I can't find a solution for this. Any help would be really great. I am new to LinQ so not really sure on what I am doing.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Message = "Comparison operators not supported for type 'System.String[]'."

Comment: Do you have a using directive for System.Linq? `using System.Linq;` If so, what .Net version are you programming for?

Comment: The `string.Split(',')` returns a string array, you need to add `System.Linq` namespace to use `Contains` for arrays.

Comment: @RomanoZumbé I have using System.Linq; and I am using .net version 4.7